# how to implement multithreading in java application

Tags: java, multithreading

I am having a class with a method callWapper

```
    public void callWrapper{
       setUnreadReceiptCount(wrapper.getWorkFlowCount(us, "unread", "receipt",Constants.Open));

       setWorklistFilesCount(wrapper.getWorkFlowCount(us, "unread", "file","worklist"));
    }
```

but, I wanted to implement these two calls in two different threads.
   And I implemented run method as follows

```
   public void run(){
     Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
     UserSession us=(UserSession)session.get("user");
     try{
      if (t.getName().equals ("UnreadReceiptCount")){

      setUnreadReceiptCount(wrapper.getWorkFlowCount(us, "unread", "receipt",Constants.Open));  

        }
     if (t.getName().equals ("UnreadFileCount")){

     setWorklistFilesCount(wrapper.getWorkFlowCount(us, "unread", "file","worklist"));

      }
    }catch(EGOVException e){
        log.info(e.toString());
    }
 }
```

But, here the code is not getting executed after getting a userSession object.Can't understand why?

I am new to it, so please tell whether I am doing the correct thing or not

Comment: Can you provide, from where you `start()` threads ? What is here `t` stands for?

Comment: I called it from callWrapper method                                                                t= new Thread (this,"UnreadReceiptCount");                                               t.start();                                                                                                                                                     Both the methods run() and callWrapper method are in the same class.

Comment: That means you are creating single thread `t` not `t1` ,`t2`. Right?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the 2 method calls in 2 different threads as follows(please see the comments inline):

```
public void callWrapper{
    Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
    final UserSession us=(UserSession)session.get("user");
  //defining thread 1
     Thread t1 =  new Thread(new Runnable(){

            public void run() {
                 // calling first method
                    setUnreadReceiptCount(wrapper.getWorkFlowCount(us, "unread", "receipt",Constants.Open));

            }});
        //defining thread 2
        Thread t2 =  new Thread(new Runnable(){

            public void run() {
                     // calling second method
                    setWorklistFilesCount(wrapper.getWorkFlowCount(us, "unread", "file","worklist"));

            }});

        t1.start();// starting thread 1
        t2.start();// starting thread 1

         // if you want to wait the current execution until both threads finish
         // you can join them as below.
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
}
```

**Update**

As per your comment if you want to go with your code no problem just change a few as below:

```
public void callWrapper{
        Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
        final UserSession us=(UserSession)session.get("user");
      //defining thread 1
         Thread t1 =  new Thread(this,"UnreadReceiptCount");


     //defining thread 2
         Thread t2 =  new Thread(this,"UnreadFileCount");   


            t1.start();// starting thread 1
            t2.start();// starting thread 1

             // if you want to wait the current execution until both threads finish
             // you can join them as below.
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
    }
```

and in the `run()` method change the thread name check `t.getName()` to `Thread.currentThread().getName()` in both `if` conditions.

Comment: Your comment helped, but just wanted to ask can't we call run for the two separate threads without the use of inner classes because I have to make the outer class variables as final, which is to be avoided.